# jQuery on draggable change axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bug with draggable in jQuery. When I rotate image it change axis. Here is [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/cna275jb/2/).
 My javascript code for rotation:

```
var angle = 0;
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
    angle = (angle+90)%360;
    document.getElementById('image').className = "rotate" + angle;
    }
```

How can I fix it?
Thank for every answer.

Comment: Fiddle here for keeping the image on the same axis https://jsfiddle.net/cna275jb/5/ I can't seem to get the draggable element inside to behave, looks like other people have run into this problem too, not finding a good solution yet.

Comment: Does the image need to be a background image?

Comment: Do not be. Mainly it to rotate.

Answer (score 0):

I think `transform-origin` property will helps to solve problem

```
 #image{
  position:absolute;
  background-image: url(https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2013/10/18/09/15/flower-197343_960_720.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  width: 350px;
  height: 220px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
    #crop{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        position:absolute;
        cursor: move;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 500px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
        background: transparent;
        z-index: 1;
    }
#image.rotate90 {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
  transform-origin: top left;
}
#image.rotate180 {
    transform: rotate(180deg) translate(-100%,-100%);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(-100%,-100%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(-100%,-100%);
    transform-origin: top left;
}
#image.rotate270 {
    transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
  transform-origin: top left;
}
```

By default, the origin of a transform is "50% 50%", which is exactly in the center of any given element. Changing the origin to "top left" (as in the demo above) causes the element to use the top left corner of the element as a rotation point.

Values can be lengths, percentages or the keywords `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom`, and `center`.